# automatic main method netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, program-entry-point

Does anyone know how to change the settings for the automatic creation of the main method in Netbeans (for C++) at least?

The problem is that the main method that is automatically created forgets to

```
#include <iostream>
```

So when I do a simple "helloworld" program, even though it does "*using namespace std*", I get an error on the line with the *cout* and the *endl*.

```
# include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cout << "Hello!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why would you want to do that? Are all your main methods directly printing to screen?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can change it in the menu:

tools->models, choose the template that you want to change and click in "open in editor"

I never try it, but you can try and see if it works

Comment: Thanks!  It's actually Tools -> Templates -> C++ -> C++ Main File.